# How can I see values in tensor object? How can we see what's going on inside tensor object?

Tags: tensorflow, conv-neural-network

Why can't I see values in the tensorflow object? I don't know what values are going in object and how to see them. Seeing values in objects will solve my problem. I am finding tensorflow difficult because you can't see what's going on inside objects.

I have tried tf.Print() but it is not working

How can I see "predict_op" value? I don't know what is inside it. It is really important for me to see the values.

```py
        predict_op = tf.argmax(Z3, 1) #Will return max value column index.
        correct_prediction = tf.equal(predict_op, tf.argmax(Y, 1))
        # Calculate accuracy on the test set
        accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, "float"))
        train_accuracy = accuracy.eval({X: X_train, Y: Y_train})
        test_accuracy = accuracy.eval({X: X_test, Y: Y_test})
        print("Train Accuracy:", train_accuracy)
        print("Test Accuracy:", test_accuracy)
```

Also if I run below code it gives error because I don't know what "tf.argmax(Y, 1)" is giving me.

```py
 con = tf.confusion_matrix(labels=tf.argmax(Y, 1), 
        predictions=tf.argmax(Z3, 1))
        sess = tf.Session()
        with sess.as_default():
             print(sess.run(con))
```

Answer (score 1):

In tensorflow, a tensor is, roughly, something that has a shape, a numerical representation *in some curcumstances*. Namely, a variable is a tensor and a tf.matmul produces a tensor, and a tf.placeholder is a tensor. All of them have a shape, but act drastically different when it comes to "what is a value of a tensor question?".

A variable once initialized always has a value - that is what we all are familiar with. A tensor like tf.matmul is an operation. Operations only describe what should be done with it's inputs. Operations only have value once you provide an input (or an input of an input, if op depends on another op). They are like functions, that descrive what to do, but you can never tell what is the ouput without providing an input. Placeholders, while still being a tensor, never have a value at all.

That said, if you, for example, want to debug a line `tf.matmul(a, b)` you must go on with running next code:

```
a_mul_b_op = tf.matmul(a, b)
a, b, a_mul_b = sess.run([a, b, a_mul_b_op], {x: input_x, y: input_y, etc: etc})
print(a, b, a_mul_b)
```

If you would like to read a value of variable (variables persist in memory in between calls to sess.run unlike operational tensors) you can go for either of next 2 ways that are equivalent:

```
print(var_conv42.eval())
print(sess.run([var_conv42]))
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to go through the [Introduction to TensorFlow](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/low_level_intro) article to understand how TensorFlow works. But here's a brief summary.

#### Define-by-run vs define-then-run

A TensorFlow program doesn't execute like a normal python script. A python scripts are *define-by-run* programs, meaning anything once defined you can change/see values. However TensorFlow programs are *define-then-run*. TensorFlow first builds a computational graph and then executes parts of/whole graph using a Session object. More info in the linke above.

#### Solving the problem with your code

If you want to see the value of `predict_op` you need to feed in the inputs/placeholders required to compute that particular tensor. For example say (I don't know how you are computing `Z3` so I am assuming a simple computation),

`X1 = tf.placeholder(…)
X2 = tf.placeholder(…)
Z3 = X1 + X2
predict_op = tf.argmax(Z3, 1)`

Then you need to do the following to get the value of `predict_op`,

`sess.run(predict_op, feed_dict={X1:<value>, X2:<value>})`